# Rake FileTask rebuilds despite :intemediate => :phony

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, makefile, rake

### Problem

I am trying to use [phony tasks](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/rake/phony.rb) in Rake, to prevent forced rebuild of my FileTasks.

(Exerpt from `ruby/lib/rake/phony.rb` on GitHub)

```
# Defines a :phony task that you can use as a dependency. This allows
# file-based tasks to use non-file-based tasks as prerequisites
# without forcing them to rebuild.
```

Despite using the `:phony` task, my FileTasks still rebuild. I have made an example demonstrating this.

### Example Scenario

We need to build `final.file` from `source.file`, using an `:intermediate` task.

It should **only** rebuild if `final.file` is out of date with `source.file`.  However, listing `:intermediate` as a prerequisite, forces a rebuild every time.

Using `rake/phony` and the `:phony` task as a prerequisite is supposed to fix that, but doesn't.

### Example Code:

```ruby
require 'rake/phony'

task :default => 'final.file'

file 'final.file' => ['source.file', :intermediate] do |f|
  touch f.name
end

# Marked as phony, so should not force FileTask to rebuild
task :intermediate => [:phony] do |t|
  puts "#{t.name} task"
end
```

### Problem Demonstation

```bash
$ touch source.file      # Create the source file
$ rake                   # Run Rake to build 'final.file'
intermediate task
touch final.file
$ rake                   # Rake should NOT rebuild, but does.     <<<<<<<<
intermediate task
touch final.file
```

---

#### Version

As you can see, I am using a more recent version of Rake than the one which introduced phony tasks (which was 0.9.4), so `:phony` should work.

```bash
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
$ rake -V
rake, version 10.4.2
```

Comment: I will leave this link here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Looking back, this is a horrible question. It was late and I was frustrated. I appreciate you being polite about it. Good link too. Bookmarked.

Comment: I have re-written my question.  I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Very good question, I've never heard about phony, but tried to reproduce your issue and seems like it should work according to code, but it doesn't. Hopefully someone will throw light on this.

Comment: Is this the type of thing I should be opening an Issue on Ruby's GitHub for?

Comment: Yes, you can try and there are more chances to receive an answer of how it works or why it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I guess rake/phony is a gem?  It's not something built into rake, I don't think, I've never seen it before.

Maybe this one? https://github.com/floere/phony  But that seems like it might have nothing to do with what you're talking about, so maybe that's not it, and you are using something else.

Whatever it is you are using, you could try posting an Issue on their github, or otherwise asking them a question if their readme has other preferred methods of receiving questions. It might be a bug in that gem, or maybe that gem doesn't do what you expect.

It's likely few readers here are familiar with that gem, and at any rate don't have the interest to read your lengthy post/question where you paste a huge chunk of source code.

Since we don't know what it is or what it's supposed to do, we don't really have a way to know if it's a bug in that gem or if you're doing it wrong, and while there are lots of people on the internet who enjoy helping out by answering a targetted question on something they are familiar with, there are very few who enjoy going through a vaguely worded "Am I doing something wrong or is it broken?" question that pastes in gigantic swathes of source material, on something they are not familiar with.

Comment: [rake/phony is build into Rake.](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/rake/phony.rb)
I have also re-written my post to be more concise.  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think lib/rake/task.rb has a broken definition of "timestamp" method.

Here is what I think it should be:

```
def timestamp # on Task
  prerequisite_tasks.collect { |pre| pre.timestamp }.max || Time.now
end
```

I found this information in this page:
http://blog.zenspider.com/blog/2012/01/simulating-phony-in-rake.html

So one hack to fix it is to re-open the Task class and redefine the timestamp method like so:

```
require 'rake/phony'                                                             

task :default => %w[targetA]                                                     

file targetA: :test do |t|                                                       
  sh "touch #{t.name}"                                                           
end                                                                              

task :test do |t|                                                                
  p t.name                                                                       
end                                                                              
task :test => :phony                                                             

class Rake::Task                                                                 
  def timestamp                                                                  
    prerequisite_tasks.collect { |pre| pre.timestamp }.max || Time.now           
  end                                                                            
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess rake/phony is a gem? It's not something built into rake, I don't think, I've never seen it before.

No, it's part of Rake:

https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/phony.rb

It can be used only for File tasks, as a dependency, so that Rake stops complaining that it doesn't know how to build that dependency.

A basic usage example:

```
require 'rake/phony'
file "doc.html" => "doc.md"
file "doc.md" => :phony
```

This is taken from an actual Rakefile I use:

```
require 'rake/phony'
LIB_ES_SOURCES = FileList['alan_en/StartLib/*.i']
LIB_ES_SOURCES.each do |lib_src|
  file 'alan_en/cloak/cloakv3.a3c' => "#{lib_src}"
  file lib_src => :phony
end
```

where I need every `*.i` in the `alan_en/StartLib/` folder to depend on the status of the `alan_en/cloak/cloakv3.a3c` (a compiled VM file); but then Rake would complain that it didn't know how to build all those `.i` files, hence the line that creates a File task for each `.i` file, making it dependent on `:phony`.

Once you `require 'rake/phony'` the `:phony` task is immediately available, and you can assign it as the dependency of any File task. It will never require executing the task since its always mimicking an up to date status, so it won't execute any custom code either (it's what its name indicates: a dummy/phony/fake task).